# Are there objects which are close to being balanced block designs?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

This question, which is combinatorial, is derived from a practical situation.  I run a class for which the final assessment is a short presentation.  For each presentation, I then get a few of the other students to evaluate it.  Suppose there are $v$ students.  What I want are $b=v$ subsets of size $k$ from $S=\{1,2,3,\ldots,v\}$, which satisfy:

1. each element $i\in S$ occurs in the same number $r$ of subsets
2. each pair of students occurs in the same number $\lambda$ of subsets

Clearly what I'm asking for is a balanced incomplete block design.  For instance, if I had 7 students, and I decided that each presentation would be evaluated by 3 others, I could form such a list of subsets from the finite projective plane of size 7.  This table shows how each student would be evaluated by three others:

```
1: 3,6,7
2: 3,4,5
3: 2,5,7
4: 1,5,6
5: 2,4,6
6: 1,4,7
7: 1,2,3
```

However of course such block designs don't exist for all orders.  What happens if I have, say, 10 students?  Then I need a sort of unbalanced design where the blocks may be of equal sizes, as well as the number of blocks in which each element is a member, but the number of pairs might be different.

How do I find such an object, in such a way that the differences (say of the number of times each pair appears) is minimized?

There is a BIBD for $b=v=16$, $k=r=6$ and $\lambda=2$.  I could for example, order the blocks in such a way that $i$ is an element of the $i$-th block, and for each presentation $i$, choose all the other students in that $i$-th block.  This has every presentation evaluated by 5 students.  But what if I want only 4 evaluators?  How "close" to a BIBD can I get?

Comment: Thanks, Morgan - that's pretty much what I thought, especially as my question is quite ill-posed.  What I've done for 16 x 4 is create 4 random permutations p_i so that for every j between 1 and 16,  p_i(j) != p_k(j) when i != k.  In other words, no two permutations agree - each one is a derangement of each of the others.   This is the best I can do, and although the pairs range from not at all to occurring up to three times, it's OK for my purposes.